# Writing linked list functions

Tags: c, linked-list

The following function exchanges the first node in the list with the second node and returns a pointer to the front of the edited list. If the original list contains fewer than two nodes, no changes are made, and the original pointer to the front of the list will be returned.

This function was written by a professor, but I am having trouble understanding why he sets
`list->next = newFront->next`.

I understand that he creates a new pointer to equal the address of the second node and the next of that newly created pointer will equal the address of the first node but why is it necessary to set the address of the second node in the original list equal to `newFront->next`: `list->next = newFront->next`. Is this step even necessary?

Here is the entire code:

```
struct node {
     int data;
     struct node *next;
};

struct node* swapFirstTwo(struct node* list) {
     if(list == NULL || list->next == NULL) return list;
     struct node* newFront = list->next;
     list->next = newFront->next;
     newFront->next = list;
     return newFront;
}
```

Comment: You already understand this for lists with zero or one element: now just draw it out for lists with two and three elements and work through it.  It's easier to do on paper, so I'm not going to kill myself with ASCII art unless you still can't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `list->next = newFront-next` ensures that the third element in the list (if there is one), and hence all following elements, is correctly linked with `list`, which has become the second element.

Say there was originally 3 elements in the list, `element1`, `element2` and `element3`. Your list looks like this:

```
element1 => element2 => element3
```

You set `newFront = list->next`, which is `element2` since `list = element1`, which effectively moves `element2` to the start. Then, to prevent `element3` "falling off", you need to set `element1->next` to `element2->next` (which is now the same as `newFront->next`) to get the following:

```
element2 (i.e. newFront) => element3
element1 (i.e. list) => element3
```

This means that the element that's now going to be second in the list (`element1` a.k.a. `list`) correctly points to the third element in the list. The only thing remaining is to actually make `element1` the second item in the list, which is achieved by setting `newFront->next` to `list`, which is in fact `element1`. So you now have:

```
element2 (i.e. newFront) => element1 (i.e. list) => element3
```

Note that whatever `element3` links to is unaffected, so this still works just fine even if there are four or more elements in the list.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. it makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 0):

`list` is the (original) first item in the list and `newFront` is the (original) second.  Assigning
`list->next = newFront->next` gets the pointer to the *third* item in the list, and stores it into what used to be the first item, since it's now going to be the second item.  Without that step, you'd end up with the two nodes pointing to each other, and the remainder of the list would be lost.